# Rails - Move view's javascript code to javascript files

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, erb

First let me tell you that I've searched for this and didn't manage to find any answer for my problem.

I have a lot of Javascript on my layouts/application.html.haml file:

```
### at the end of application.html.haml file

- if @instance_variable.condition

    :javascript
        // a lot js/jQuery code

    :javascript
        // more js code that uses #{ @instance.vars }

    - if @another_condition.using.ruby.cody

        :javascript
            // more js code that uses #{ @instance.vars }
```

And I'm using instance vars within this code, which means that this vars will only be declared on the controller (application controller). As this is the application layout, these scripts run on every page of my website (and that's what I need of course).

What I want is to move all this code to a js.erb file (or .haml if possible). First - because is easier to manage this code in a separate file; Second - because I don't want to have `<script> // a lot of js code </script>` tags at the end of every html file, I want to have a `<script async src='link'/>` tag only.

Also I'm including already the `application.coffee` at the beginning of the file, but I need this script tag at the end of the html files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answer Uzbekjon, but after some research I found a way to do exactly what I wanted :)

In my 'layouts/application.html.haml' file, I added a script tag:

```
### at the end of application.html.haml file

%script{async: 'async', src: application_scripts_path}
```

Then I added this path to routes:

```
get 'application_scripts' => 'controller#application_scripts', as: :application_scripts
```

Then I just had to set this action `application_scripts`on my controller and create a new view (app/views/controller/application_scrips.js.erb):

```
class Controller < ActionController::Base

    # 1
    protect_from_forgery except: :application_scripts

    def application_scripts

        # 2
        if condition.that.tells.me.this.request.is.valid

            # 3
            render formats: [:js] and return

        end
        render plain: ''
    end
```

These steps were of course the harder ones to find out:

- 1 - I had to disable this protection, or else I would get this error:

  > ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest at /application_scripts
  >
  > > Security warning: an embedded  tag on another site requested protected JavaScript. If you know what you're doing, go ahead and disable forgery protection on this action to permit cross-origin JavaScript embedding.
- 2 - To make sure that no other site can request this script file (not that it could be a problem for me, but I preferred this way) I added a condition that makes sure the request comes from my website. In this case I was just checking if a user as logged in.
- 3 - The `formats: [:js]` tells Rails that the view is not .html, instead it's a .js file 'application_scripts.js.erb'

Finally I just had to move all my code from the application.html.haml file to the view file 'application_scripts.js.erb' and convert from haml code to erb as well.

```
<% @instance_variable.condition %>

    // a lot js/jQuery code

    // more js code that uses <%= @instance.vars %>

    <% @another_condition.using.ruby.cody %>

        // more js code that uses <%= @instance.vars %>

    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using partials for this. Because, your code uses variables, this means it changes depending on your variables. If you put them into a separate javascript file, the browser wouldn't know about the changes and use a cached file. A workaround would be to add some string (that changes when vars change) at the end of your filename, but then, you would lose all the benefits of moving your javascript into separate files.

A better way would be to define variables in your `application.html.haml`, move out your javascript code into separate files and just use defined variables.

#### application.html.haml

```
- if @instance_variable.condition
    %script(src="path/to/my/script.js")

    :javascript
        = var some_var = #{@instance.vars}

    %script(src="path/to/my/second_script_that_uses_var.js")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this isn't yet what I'm looking for. I wanted Rails to generate a different js file (the same way it generates a different HTML file) every time a user asks for it. Isn't this in anyway possible?

Comment: I explained how to do it in the sentence that starts with "*A workaround would be to ...*" and explained why you **shouldn't** be doing it in the next.

Comment: But I don't want that also. You're talking about adding queries when calling the file right? I don't want these for security reasons as well, I want these vars, and these values hidden from the html view.

Comment: They would end up on a client anyways. So, you can't really talk about securing those variable right? Or do you simply use them for `if` checks?

Comment: No, I really use these vars inside the js code. And I don't want users to be able to edit them and to run these scripts on the browser console for example.
What if I had a another action/view, that when called (needed to configure routes ofc) would render a js file? Is this possible? I'm trying to test this but I'm getting errors.

Comment: I did it! I will post my answer now :)